# Cross browser way of setting IFrame to "about:blank"?

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, internet-explorer

Does anybody know a proper, cross-browser way to "empty" an IFrame? 
Is "about:blank" recognized without error across all browsers?
Is it valid to give an IFrame an empty src?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
src="javascript: ;"
```

or

```
src="javascript:void(0)"
```

This should work fine with IE and Firefox