# How do I set the current page to about:blank using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a situation where the server may not available on the current address, so I want to detect that and redirect the page to an about:blank page.

How would I go about doing that using JavaScript?

Comment: fully related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145245/does-aboutblank-work-in-all-browsers/4145334#4145334

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
window.location.href="about:blank";
```

Comment: Just got that question too. about:blank. Browser support?

Comment: All browsers I know of.

Comment: It's THIS easy? God!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
window.location.href="about:blank";
```