# JavaScript get abount:blank URL failed

Tags: javascript

In my JS code, I want to get current page URL,

so I use document.URL function, every webpage works well, except the abount:blank,

I wrote this in my code.

`console.log(document.URL);`

but there is nothing display in my Google Dev Tools Console.

I changed Chrome Source Code and WebKit Source Code, this make me can execute my own JS code when every webpage loaded.

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843288/how-do-i-set-the-current-page-to-aboutblank-using-javascript

Comment: No,No,No, I do not mean set current page to about:blank, I mean when I am on the about:blank page, how can I use JS to get current page URL.

Comment: document.URL(), seems not work

Comment: Well it's the same thing. Type `document.location.href` in console. It produces `about:blank` for me in Chrome.

Comment: Yep, in the console, it seems work well, but in my JS code, it does not work, I am very confused about this, I write these code in Chrome User Javascript Code level, this can make me to inject JS code to each page I opened.

Comment: How can you use JavaScript on a blank page other than by means of using the JS Console (address bar on older browsers)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah, other than execute JS code in the Console, I also can execute JS code in my JS file, I changed the Chrome Source Code, modified the WebKit, so when I open every webpage, my JS code could be executed

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I'd change the code so that it prints `console.log('Hi Glue')`. Chrome might be checking the URL and if it is `about:blank` might not be running your chrome alterations at all.

Comment: It was so strange, there is no error, I think if I should ask the question in the Chrome-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.location.href` seems to work on about:blank in Chrome, and should work everywhere else.

Comment: What do you mean? When you're on about:blank and you run document.location.href from the console, what do you see? Here it is working as expected for me: http://i.imgur.com/9LGoYLw.png

Comment: @Glue: What do you mean by _It seems not work well_? What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: When I execute documenet.URL or document.location.href in the console, it works well, but when I use this in my js code, it does not work, I use this JS code in Chrome User Javascript level, this can make me to inject JS code to every page I opened.

Comment: When the URL is about:blank, your code isn't on that page. You cannot execute code on that page—it's not your page to control. Maybe we're not understanding the question very well. Can you post your code or a jsfiddle to demonstrate the scenario?