# Hyperlink to about:blank

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is it valid to all browsers to link to about:blank with a HTML a tag with href attribute like this?

```
<a href="about:blank">about:blank</a>
```

EDIT: This question answer to the support of about:blank in browsers: [Does about:blank work in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145245/does-aboutblank-work-in-all-browsers)
My question is: work the link in all browsers? (in current Firefox yes).

Comment: It's unclear what you're hoping to achieve with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does about:blank work in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145245/does-aboutblank-work-in-all-browsers)

Comment: please see my edit. @ratbum: link to a blank page without a URL.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this on all modern browsers and it works the way you'd want it to. In future, please try it yourself first.

Comment: We expect askers to test things themselves in *all* modern browsers before asking a question about the breadth of support for a feature?

Comment: I mean I do... that's what I had to do to answer the question.