# Is an empty iframe src valid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want an iframe to initially have `src` as blank and then once the page loads; call a JS function and then set the `src` value to an actual one..

So is `<iframe src="#" />` valid OR do I need to use something else like `javascript:;`, etc

Comment: I see `about:blank` everywhere.

Comment: I believe if you omit the `src` attribute browsers default to `about:blank`.

Comment: Of you leave the `src` empty, the browser will figure it out. Not all browsers might have a `about:blank`.

Comment: @Jim, omitting the `src` attribute in secure pages will trigger the infamous "this page contains both secure and unsecure items" message in some versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I just found out that jQuery will fire the document ready event twice, because of the # as a src. Took me quite awhile to find out ;-)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

just `<iframe src='about:blank'></iframe>`

Comment: Does src='about:blank' work in all major browsers...IE 7/8, FF, Safari, Chrome, etc

Comment: The IE 9 sends an request to the server with path "null" with src="about:blank" :(

Comment: @powtac Does it do the same with src=""?

Answer (score 58):

The HTML 5 working draft, [section 4.8.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element), says (emphasis mine):

> The `src` attribute gives the address of
> a page that the nested browsing
> context is to contain. The attribute,
> if present, must be a **valid non-empty
> URL** potentially surrounded by spaces.

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), valid URLs must begin with a [scheme name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1), and relative references cannot only consist in a [fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5).

Therefore, `#` is not a valid URL, and should not be used as the value of the `src` attribute.

Use [about:blank](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#about:blank) instead.

Comment: No, the valid non-empty URL is required to be a valid URI *reference* as defined by RFC3986 section 4.1, not necessarily a valid URI. Otherwise you couldn't use a relative URL as an iframe src, which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: @Mike, you're right, and `#` is also an invalid relative reference. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Is a Javascript: URI valid?  Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1689215/328397

Comment: As a side note, if you use `#` as your src value, Chrome will "jump" the page down to the iframe. Imagine if you had an anchor tag `<a name="anchor"></a>` right above your iframe. Chrome behaves as if your URL was `mypage.html#anchor`.

Comment: The "if present" suggests that you can also omit the `src` attribute entirely (`<iframe></iframe>` with no `src=`).

Answer (score 31):

**No, it is *not valid* to specify an empty iframe src.**

You should use `<iframe src="about:blank" />`.

`#` is meant to be a **reference to an anchor within the current page** (or, often used as a routing scheme when working with AJAX requests). Using it as the source of an iframe would be senseless, since an iframe does not reference content on the current page and is not used with AJAX requests.

`about:blank` is a **cross-browser standard** to display a blank document.

**Update June 8th 2012:**

It seems that the ['living' spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element) no longer renders an iframe invalid if the `src` attribute is missing:

> If, when the element is created, the srcdoc attribute is not set, and
> the src attribute is either also not set or set but its value cannot
> be resolved, the browsing context will remain at the initial
> about:blank page.

If both of these attributes, however, are not set, the browsing context will default to `about:blank`. To provide proper backwards compatibility, it's recommendable to be verbose and, for now, provide the `about:blank` URL.

Comment: For those looking for a full reference or "proof", the `about:` scheme was [standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About%3a_URI_scheme) in 2010.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you can also leave out the src completely:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-iframe-element

> If, when the element is created, the srcdoc attribute is **not set**, and
>   the src attribute is either **also not set** or set but its value cannot
>   be resolved, the browsing context will remain at the initial
>   about:blank page.

Comment: One annoyance that might trip you up there, is in Chrome, where `src=""` will cause the previously loaded page to reload if you reload the parent page, which probably isn't what you want. `about:blank` is probably a better bet.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `about:blank` you may use javascript as an `src` for your `iframe` like the following example:

```
<iframe name="TV" id="tv" style="width:100%; background: #800000" src="javascript:document.write('<h3>Results Window</h3>')"></iframe>
```

The above example will initialize an `iframe` with maroon background that has a simple message `<h3>Results Window</h3>`. However, the targets of your links should equals the `iframe` `name` attribute i.e in that example `TV`.

### Notice:

Some external website may block requesting their pages from another origin. Try to change the URLs of the hyperlinks in the example below to `yahoo.com` or `google.com`, for example, and checkout your browser's console.

[Jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/xivatunita/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `about:blank` in the `src` attribute (as mentioned by ariel earlier), otherwise it would throw an error when serving from a secure page.

A secure page `https` would throw an error of possibly un-secure data on the secure website.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the iframe through Javascript, so you wouldn't need to have a blank one in the HTML:

(jQuery example)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("<iframe />").attr("src", "http://www.bbc.co.uk/").appendTo("body");
});
</script>
```

Adding the iframe with Javascript allows graceful degradation - users without Javascript won't see a blank iframe.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the about URI scheme standard, about:blank is probably the best option as it has very good browser support.

> about:blank   Returns a blank HTML document with the media type
>   text/html and character encoding UTF-8. This is widely used to load
>   blank pages into browsing contexts, such as iframes within HTML, which
>   may then be modified by scripts.
>   [You can see further here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 0):

For the record

Let's say the next example (Firefox 58 but may be its present in all browsers).

```
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<iframe src='about:blank'></iframe>
```

Iframe is loaded BEFORE the css so the render of the page is visible before the css is loaded. I.e. for a split of a second, the page looks without a css.

Instead:

```
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<iframe src='blank.html'></iframe>
```

It works fine, the css is loaded and the iframe is loaded finally.

Answer (score 0):

if you do call your iframe with
`javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(VARİABLES,,true,,false,)`
in server side you can again have a src=""

Answer (score 0):

Raw HTML and JavaScript example.

You could just load in your iframe when some event happens. As long as you have a HTML element ready to accept an iframe.

Below, an iframe will appear only if this paragraph element is clicked. So technically it will be blank until a click happens.

HTML

```
<body>
<p id=iFrameParagraph></p>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var pFrame = document.getElementById("iFrameParagraph"); //iframe paragraph

pFrame.addEventListener('click' ,function() {
    pFrame.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"./path/to/file\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"400\" width=\"95%\"></iframe>"; 
});
```